# Idiom to initialize C++ class to zero

Tags: c++, initialization, zero, idioms, construction

Consider the following C++ class:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    explicit Point() =default; // 1
    explicit Point(int x_, int y_): x(x_), y(y_) { } // 2
};
```

The second constructor is useful for creating a `Point` with specific `x` and `y` values. The first exists so that I can default construct a `Point`. However, for efficiency, it is `default`ed and does not set `x` and `y` to zero. If I did want to set all members to zero, I could have another constructor:

```
explicit Point(int val) : x(val), y(val) { } // 3
```

This way, I can choose to either default initialize the `Point`, or initialize it with all members being set to zero:

```
Point p1;    // Don't initialize members.
Point p2(0); // Initialize all members to zero.
```

The problem with the third constructor is that I can really pass any value, not just zero. For example:

```
Point p(1); // Both x and y set to 1! Is this the intent? If so,
            // probably should have used Point p(1, 1) instead.
```

Another way would be to have a special type which represents a zero or default value and pass that to the constructor:

```
explicit Point(Default) : x(0), y(0) { } // 4
```

Where `Default` can be defined simply as:

```
struct Default { };
```

Then, I can control when I want the `Point` to be initialized with default values:

```
Point p1;            // Don't initialize members.
Point p2(Default()); // Initialize members with default values.
```

Which method would be considered better, the method with the sentinel type `Default` (no. 4), or the constructor which takes a single value and initializes all members to that value (no. 3)? What are the pros/cons of the two methods? Or is there another better mechanism to do this?

**Edit:** Please note that this simple class was chosen for illustration; in reality, there might be many more members which need specific default values to be considered *"initialized"*.

Comment: Note that you can also use value initialization. `Point p{};`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your life easier, make simple data structs like this aggregates:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Now you can use aggregate initialization:

```
Point p;      // members uninitialized
Point p{};    // members set to 0
Point p{1,2}; // members set to 1,2
```

Answer (score 2):

The most common practice that I see for this is to implement the no argument constructor with an initialization list that contains every member of the class set to whatever default value you want.

```
Point(): x(0), y(0) { }
```

The reasoning behind this is that you probably never want to instantiate an object without initializing the members to some known value, so you don't actually want that default constructor to exist.

Comment: I think this is the approach taken for `std::complex`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    explicit Point(int x_ = 0, int y_ = 0): x(x_), y(y_) {}
};

Point p1;        // 0, 0
Point p2(1);     // 1, 0
Point p3(1, 10); // 1, 10
```